# How to delete all lines except lines that include TRUNCATE - INSERT

Tags: shell, ksh

I have created a script that formats all of my PL/SQL files into a simple file that has pairs of values,  its quite hard to explain, i think it will be easier if you just look at the file;

```
PROCEDURE VALIDA_CAMBIO_GPR
TRUNCATE TMP_MOD_PVA
INSERT TMP_MOD_PVA
PROCEDURE AJUSTAR_FECHAS
INSERT PRO_TDA_VARLOG_ALM
PROCEDURE DEPURAR_CAMBIOS_GPR
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0001
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0002
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0003
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0005
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0007
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0008
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0009
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0010
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0011
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
```

Ok, this file goes on for 4000 lines, but i dont need all of the lines, all i want are the pairs of TRUNCATE and INSERTS of the same table, so for example out of the last file i would only want to keep the name of the procedure containing the pair, and the pair. f.e

```
PROCEDURE VALIDA_CAMBIO_GPR
TRUNCATE TMP_MOD_PVA
INSERT TMP_MOD_PVA
```

As you can see, the TRUNCATE and INSERT affect the same table, there may also be more than one pair per procedure. How could i do this?
I DO NOT WANT all the procedure's that dont have these pairs, and i also don't want any truncates of inserts that don't have their pair.
Sorry for the bad explanation, if oyu have problems understanding just comment and i'll do my best to upgrade.

PD: Im using ksh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '$1=="PROCEDURE"{p=$0;next} p && $1=="TRUNCATE"{t=$2;next} t==$2 && $1=="INSERT"{
     print p; print "TRUNCATE" t; print "INSERT" t; print ""; t=""}' file
PROCEDURE VALIDA_CAMBIO_GPR
TRUNCATETMP_MOD_PVA
INSERTTMP_MOD_PVA
```

Comment: Ok it works, but does this also include the procedure's that have more than one pair of truncate-inserts?

Comment: That wasn't in your question so no it won't print them. Can you provide a modified sample data for that.

Comment: I updated the answer now to take care of multiple pairs under same procedure.

Comment: Ok thankyou so much, i'm not great with awk, do you know any good tutorial pages about awk? Great stuff!

Comment: You're welcome. For `awk` just search for `awk tutorial` on Google and top 2-3 search results are pretty good awk tutorials.

Comment: hello @anubhava , i have had some problems with the script i created thanks to you, the question has changed because i have to include a new line, can i alter the question for you to be able to alter your answer? thankyou

Comment: I would suggest posting a new question so that we can take a fresh look at it.

Comment: Here is new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26338271/how-to-delete-all-lines-except-lines-that-include-truncate-insert-incluiding Thankyou