# How to delete all lines except lines that include TRUNCATE - INSERT, incluiding PACK name

Tags: shell, awk, ksh

this is an extension to this question: [How to delete all lines except lines that include TRUNCATE - INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25932500/how-to-delete-all-lines-except-lines-that-include-truncate-insert)

I had earlier asked that question because i needed some help deleting line from a generated script, thanx from some great help from anubhava i was able to solve the problem, but now the proble is that i have been asked to include the pack name into my generated script, so:

```
PROCEDURE VALIDA_CAMBIO_GPR
TRUNCATE TMP_MOD_PVA
INSERT TMP_MOD_PVA
PROCEDURE AJUSTAR_FECHAS
INSERT PRO_TDA_VARLOG_ALM
PROCEDURE DEPURAR_CAMBIOS_GPR
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0001
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0002
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0003
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0005
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0007
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0008
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0009
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0010
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0011
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
```

This was my original problem where i had a long text file with lines like that, but i wanted to delete all lines that did not have a couple of INSERT-TRUNCATE per procedure, so the result from the previous line would be

```
PROCEDURE VALIDA_CAMBIO_GPR
TRUNCATE TMP_MOD_PVA
INSERT TMP_MOD_PVA
```

To do this we used this AWK;

```
 awk '$1=="PROCEDURE"{p=$0;next} p && $1=="TRUNCATE"{t=$2;next} t==$2 && $1=="INSERT"{print p; print "TRUNCATE " t; print "INSERT " t; print ""; t=""}'
```

Ok, so up to here i have no problem, but now, when i have been told to include the PACK name obove the procedure, my text file looks like this.

```
PACK PACKENVI
PROCEDURE VALIDA_CAMBIO_GPR
TRUNCATE TMP_MOD_PVA
INSERT TMP_MOD_PVA
PACKANSI
PROCEDURE CALCULA_GRAMOS
PACK PACKBRUM
PROCEDURE AJUSTAR_FECHAS
INSERT PRO_TDA_VARLOG_ALM
PACK PACKRENSI
PROCEDURE DEPURAR_CAMBIOS_GPR
PACK PACKRENSI
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0001
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PACK PACKRENSI
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0002
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PACK PACKRENSI
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0003
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PACK PACKRENSI
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0005
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PACK PACKRENSI
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0007
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PACK PACKRENSI
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0008
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PACK PACKRENSI
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0009
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PACK PACKRENSI
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0010
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
PACK PACKRENSI
PROCEDURE INC_EX_0011
INSERT CABECERA_ALARMAS
```

The desired output from this text would be:

```
PACK PACKENVI
PROCEDURE VALIDA_CAMBIO_GPR
TRUNCATE TMP_MOD_PVA
INSERT TMP_MOD_PVA
```

It is pretty much the same problem as before, only that there is another line that needs to be printed when a couple of INSERT-TRUNCATE is found below a procedure below a PACK, if a procedure as more than one couple of INSERT_TRUNCATE, all pairs must be printed.

Thanks a lot, if you had trouble understanding take a look at the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk solution

```
awk '/PACK/{P=$0}/PROCEDURE/{p=$0}/TRUNCATE/{t=$0}t~$2&&/INSERT/{print P RS p RS t RS $0;P=p=t=0}' file

PACK PACKENVI
PROCEDURE VALIDA_CAMBIO_GPR
TRUNCATE TMP_MOD_PVA
INSERT TMP_MOD_PVA
```

For all further lines that need to be printed just add another `/LINE/{?=$0}` and add it to the print part as well(where `?` is a variable)

Comment: I would like an empty line after each pair found.

Comment: Thankyou for your help but i have made my own solution from my original awk

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution just modifying the original AWK, here is the new one

```
awk '$1=="PACK"{s=$0;next} s && $1=="PROCEDURE"{p=$0;next} p && $1=="TRUNCATE"{t=$2;next}
t==$2 && $1=="INSERT"{print s; print p; print "TRUNCATE " t; print "INSERT " t; print ""; t=""}'
```

Comment: The reason i didn't add to your original AWK in my answer was that quite a few parts were redundant. The `next`s are not needed, niether are the checks for whether `s` and `p` exist. Also the comparison to `$1` is probably not needed unless you expect the value to also be in $2. Finally you can use RS as a newline between each variable instead of repeatedly printing.

Comment: Thankyou for very helpfull comment, will have a look at my awk code, i'm very new to AWK and its quite hard to get used to. Thankyou, will vote your answer as correct as it did do exactly what i asked! ;)